# create jetsnack's SnackDetails like screen but with LazyColumn instead of Column(Modifier.verticalScroll(state))

Tags: android, android-jetpack-compose, android-jetpack-compose-material3

I want to create a scrolling effect like [Jetsnacks SnackDetails.kt](https://github.com/android/compose-samples/blob/main/Jetsnack/app/src/main/java/com/example/jetsnack/ui/snackdetail/SnackDetail.kt)

here they have used `Column(Modifier.verticalScroll(state))`, by using the `state.value` we can have the scrolling offset which can be used to change the other composables position on screen, e.g. `Title`. I want to achieve the same effect but In my case I have the `LazyColumn` in my body which needs `LazyListState` instead of `ScrollState`. Just want to know how to get the scroll value in `LazyListState`?

In [Jetsnacks SnackDetails.kt](https://github.com/android/compose-samples/blob/main/Jetsnack/app/src/main/java/com/example/jetsnack/ui/snackdetail/SnackDetail.kt) I want to know how to get the same effect if the

```
    @Composable
    private fun Body(
        related: List<SnackCollection>,
        scroll: ScrollState
    ) {
      Column(modifier = Modifier.verticalScroll(state)
    }
```

replaced by

```
@Composable
    private fun Body(
        related: List<SnackCollection>,
        lazyListState: lazyListState
    ) {
      LazyColumn(
        state = lazyListState
        ) 
    }
```